# Sort sub-arrays so corresponding values within each sub-array are in numerical order?

Tags: php, sorting

I need a custom sort function that will take a 2 dimensional array of values, and sort the sub-arrays so that the corresponding values within each sub-array are in numerical order. Anything with a value of -1 can be ignored.

Since this is a bit difficult to explain using words, here is an example. Starting with the following:

```
[
    ["1st"] => [ [0] =>  0    [1] =>  0    [2] =>  0 ]
    ["2nd"] => [ [0] =>  2    [1] =>  2    [2] =>  3 ]
    ["3rd"] => [ [0] =>  3    [1] => -1    [2] => -1 ]
    ["4th"] => [ [0] =>  5    [1] =>  6    [2] => 11 ]
    ["5th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] =>  3    [2] =>  4 ] 
    ["6th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] =>  4    [2] => -1 ]
    ["7th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] =>  5    [2] => 10 ]
    ["8th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] => -1    [2] =>  2 ]
    ["9th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] => -1    [2] =>  5 ]
]
```

["4th"][1] is higher than any of the other [1] column values, so it needs to be moved to the end. Next, the [2] row that has 2 values out of sequence. Once those are in their proper place, the array should look like this:

```
[
    ["1st"] => [ [0] =>  0    [1] =>  0    [2] =>  0 ]
    ["8th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] => -1    [2] =>  2 ]
    ["2nd"] => [ [0] =>  2    [1] =>  2    [2] =>  3 ]
    ["3rd"] => [ [0] =>  3    [1] => -1    [2] => -1 ]
    ["5th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] =>  3    [2] =>  4 ]
    ["9th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] => -1    [2] =>  5 ]    
    ["6th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] =>  4    [2] => -1 ]
    ["7th"] => [ [0] => -1    [1] =>  5    [2] => 10 ]
    ["4th"] => [ [0] =>  5    [1] =>  6    [2] => 11 ]
]
```

With the -1 values ignored, the [0] column now reads "0, 2, 3, 5", the [1] column reads "0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6", and the [2] column reads "0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11".

This requires that the rows are "in agreement" so to speak, and will not work for every case. I generally understand what I need to do here, I'm just not sure how to write it as actual code.

I will be using this to determine the order in which elements will be displayed on a website, so I need a solution in PHP. (I will probably want a JavaScript version as well, but once I have something working in PHP, I can work that out myself).

Comment: Heard of [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) ?

Comment: So, it's a column wise sorting. You could try your javascript version and try for PHP later. This will help you focus only on syntax than semantics during conversion.

Comment: I know about usort(), just not how to apply it in this case. And I'm not saying a javascript implementation will be any easier or harder, just that once I have something that works, I can figure out how to adapt it.

Comment: I ended up just using a modified bubble sort because I couldn't figure out any other way to deal with the -1 values.